# Query Multiple Conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am keeping track of a few things on my site and im using a lot of queries because they need different conidtions

for example

```
$example = mysql_query("SELECT column FROM table WHERE column = 'Value1'");
$example_row = mysql_num_rows($example);

$example1 = mysql_query("SELECT column FROM table WHERE column = 'Value2'");
$example_row1 = mysql_num_rows($example1);
```

And so on, the value is always different so im having trouble finding a way to make this in to one query where i could still get different rows count for different values, is it possible?

I could test the row to see if it matches the value

```
if ($row == 'value'){

}
```

Multiple times but it still seems bad

Comment: If you want to have results in two separate PHP variable ($row1, $row2) It's better not to combine the queries. But it's possible to store VALUE1, VALUE2, ... ,VALUE100 in an array an getting the result by looping on that array.

Comment: Do you just need the count of each result? mysql_num_rows will returns the count of results. If it's the case do SELECT count(*) FROM etc

Answer (score 2):

Use [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column IN('Value1', 'Value2');
```

Comment: Also, you should use mysqli

Comment: How would i get the rows matching value1 and separate rows matching value2 though?

Comment: Rows are always separate unless you do something to intentionally group them. If you want to keep them organized then use an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @ChristianStewart or `PDO`

Comment: You can add "ORDER BY column" to the end of the query.

Comment: "WHERE column IN('Value1', 'Value2');" is equal to "column = 'Value1' or column = 'Value2'"

Comment: If i select name where value = 'bob' and it gave me one row, then i also want to select name value = 'pat', normally if i want both as seperate rows i would need 2 queries to use the two conditions, im just counting the rows, so if i done a mysql_num_rows it would return one row for either bob or pat, when i want to be able to have one for each

Comment: Yes, it gives me one value (count) as im using num rows, i want a count of both conditions

Comment: If you want a count of each you'll either need to add that to the query or add a separate query to get the counts. (You also should specify that the count is important in your question as that would be helpful to know).

Comment: See my answer, also noticed mysql_num_rows at the very last, assumed it was mysql_get_result or sth.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the count per value:

```
$values = ["value1", "value2", ...];
$query = "SELECT ";

for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++)
{
    $query .= "SUM(IF(column = '$values[$i]')) AS v$i";

    if($i != count($values) - 1)
        $query .= ","; //Only add ',' if it's not the last value

    $query .= " "; //We need the spaces at the end of every line
}

$query .= "FROM table";

//Let mysql do its work, run the query etc., store the resultset in $row;
```

Now you can dynamically iterate through the resultset:

```
$results = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++)
{
    $string = "v"+ $i;
    $results[] = $row[$string];
}
```